# Read data from memory mmap

Tags: c, shared-memory, mmap

here is my question. I'm trying to make a simple shared memory program. Basically the deal is that in one part of the code (Program1) needs to open the file read the data (if there is any because there is gona be one first time that the file is opened) erase the data and write a new vector into it, the other part (Program 2) needs to read the data erase the data and write new data.

Now first i made this example. (Program 1)

```c
int i,  result;
int archivo,creaarchivo;
char  array[10];
srand(time(NULL));
//caddr_t mcompartida;
void *mcompartida;

//archivo=open(RUTA,O_CREAT|O_EXCL|O_RDWR,(mode_t)0777);
archivo=open(RUTA,O_RDWR,(mode_t)0777);
if (archivo<0)
    {
        return (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, "Error al leer ");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    result = lseek(archivo, SIZE-1, SEEK_SET);

    if (result == -1)
    {
        close(archivo);
        return (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, "Error al invocar lseek() memoria");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    result = write(archivo, "",1);

    if (result != 1)
    {
        close(archivo);
        return (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, "Error escribiendo los bytes en memoria");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    //mcompartida = mmap((caddr_t)0, SIZE, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, archivo,    0);
    mcompartida = mmap(0, SIZE, PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, archivo, 0);

    if (mcompartida == (caddr_t)-1)
    {
        close(archivo);
        return (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, "Error mapeando el archivo");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    close(archivo);

// Se escribe en la memoria compartida

for(i=0; i<10; i++)
{
   sprintf(array,"%d ",i);
   strcat((char *)mcompartida,array);
}

// Se libera la memoria compartida con munmap

munmap (mcompartida, SIZE);

if (munmap(mcompartida, SIZE) == -1)
{
    return (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, "Error liberando la memoria compartida");
}

return (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, "Memoria Compartida Creada =D!");
```

In the first example i'm trying to write ten numbers as a vector but i made it with strcat wich only concatenates the data. (for now i'm not erasing data and reading data just writing)

Second program (Program 2)

```c
int i,  result;
int archivo,creaarchivo;
char array_rx[10];
srand(time(NULL));
void *mcompartida;

archivo=open(RUTA,O_RDWR,(mode_t)0777);

if (archivo<0)
{
    return (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, "Error al leer ");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

mcompartida = mmap(0, SIZE, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, archivo, 0);

if (mcompartida == -1)
{
    close(archivo);
    return (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, "Error mapeando el archivo");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

close(archivo);

// Se lee de memoria compartida

for(i=0; i<10; i++)
{
  strcat((char *)array_rx,mcompartida);
  sscanf(array_rx,"%d",i);
}


// Se libera la memoria compartida con munmap

munmap (mcompartida, SIZE);

if (munmap(mcompartida, SIZE) == -1)
{
    return (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, "Error liberando la memoria compartida");
 }

    return (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, "Memoria Compartida Leida =D");
```

I'm trying to read the data that program 1 wrote but i can't, any help? 
I tried just making sscanf first, but it didn't work, so i thought i could use strcat to copy the data from shared memory to my array_rx but it neither worked.

this is in C and i'm returning a message using JNI in Android Developers tool.

Answer (score 0):

Incorrect usage of `sscanf()`.

```
const char *p = mcompartida;
for(i=0; i<10; i++) {
  //strcat((char *)array_rx,mcompartida);
  //sscanf(array_rx,"%d",i);
  int offset; // Offset where scanning stopped.
  if (1 != sscanf(p, "%d%n", &array_rx[i], &offset)) {
    break; // handle format error
  }  
  p += offset;
}
```